# sql trigger to stop duplicates across row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table with multiple records:

- User_Name     ( e.g. 'TOM')
- Question_ID    (eg 'q002')
- Answer         (e.g. 'D')

i want to create a trigger so that no one can submit an answer to the same question twice.
It **has to be a trigger** only.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_Check_Duplicates

ON submit_Answer

FOR INSERT
AS

IF SELECT???

PRINT 'duplicate'

raiserror('cant submit answer to same question twice')

ROLLBACK

End
```

Comment: You might want to explain **why** it can't be anything but a trigger.  Normally, this is handled by constraints so that it's impossible for it to be allowed, rather than relying on a mechanism like triggers to do the extra work for you.

Comment: @Sumo i know there are constraints and using keys that prevent this, but as the question asked I want to use a trigger to do it. this isn't for a real db

Comment: Just noticed that this is also MySql and not SQL Server.

Comment: Just in case, you can create a `UNIQUE` index on User_Name AND Question_ID, then your insertion would fails unless you specify an `IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE` clause.

Comment: But why u didn't finish that trigger you've started already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.uniqueUserQuestion 
ON dbo.submit_Answer
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.submit_Answer T 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I 
        ON T.user_name = I.user_name 
            AND T.question_id = I.question_id
    )
    BEGIN
        -- Do dupe handling here
        PRINT 'duplicate'
        raiserror('cant submit answer to same question twice')
        return
    END

    -- actually add it in
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.submit_Answer
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        INSERTED I
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

MySql does not support `INSTEAD OF` triggers, which is what you'd need to use here.  In SQL Server, you'd use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that will fire **before** the insert occurs, where you can write a check for the duplicate.  However, if you can avoid a trigger, why not use a [Stored Routine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) and just check for the duplicate before inserting?

This is, of course, if you really, really cannot use a constraint.

**Edit:** Updating answer for MSSQL.

Here's an example [right from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx):

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_INS_Employee ON Employee
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Check for duplicate Person. If there is no duplicate, do an insert.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.SSN
      FROM Person P, inserted I
      WHERE P.SSN = I.SSN))
   INSERT INTO Person
      SELECT SSN,Name,Address,Birthdate
      FROM inserted
ELSE
-- Log an attempt to insert duplicate Person row in PersonDuplicates table.
   INSERT INTO PersonDuplicates
      SELECT SSN,Name,Address,Birthdate,SUSER_SNAME(),GETDATE()
      FROM inserted
-- Check for duplicate Employee. If no there is duplicate, do an INSERT.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT E.SSN
      FROM EmployeeTable E, inserted
      WHERE E.SSN = inserted.SSN))
   INSERT INTO EmployeeTable
      SELECT EmployeeID,SSN, Department, Salary
      FROM inserted
ELSE
--If there is a duplicate, change to UPDATE so that there will not
--be a duplicate key violation error.
   UPDATE EmployeeTable
      SET EmployeeID = I.EmployeeID,
          Department = I.Department,
          Salary = I.Salary
   FROM EmployeeTable E, inserted I
   WHERE E.SSN = I.SSN
END
```

You'll obviously need to modify/simplify for your situation, but the basic context is there.

Comment: sorry its for SQL, what would the syntax be using the above 'trigger_check_duplicates' example?